# Raster subset error in R: "Error: object of type 'S4' is not subsettable"

Tags: raster, r, spatial-analyst, sp, rgdal

I am running this code in R:

```
country_template <- raster()

dimensions <- extent(124000, 463000, 2953600, 3127600)

country_template <- setExtent(country_template, dimensions)

res(country_template) <- 150

country_template <-CRS("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=90 +k=1 +x_0=250000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")

country_template[] <- 1:ncell(country_template)
```

The error **"Error in country_template[] <- 1:ncell(country_template) :
object of type 'S4' is not subsettable"**  is seen while running the last code of line. Does anyone know what might be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

In your current code, what you are doing is converting the raster into a CRS object, that's why it fails in the next line. To correctly set the CRS you have to do the following.

```
country_template <- raster()

dimensions <- extent(124000, 463000, 2953600, 3127600)

country_template <- setExtent(country_template, dimensions)

res(country_template) <- 150

crs(country_template) <- "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=90 +k=1 +x_0=250000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs" #fu

country_template[] <- 1:ncell(country_template)
```

Comment: > crs(country_template) <-"+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=90 +k=1 +x_0=250000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘crs<-’ for signature ‘"CRS"’

I get the above error while I run your code

Comment: The error you describre pops up because `country_template` is still in CRS format. Please make sure you are using my whole code in the same order. You may have to delete your old variables and create them again.

Comment: Or in one line: `country_template <- raster(ext=extent(124000, 463000, 2953600, 3127600), res=150, crs="+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=90 +k=1 +x_0=250000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")`